# How to get count from multiple tables with conditional data

Tags: mysql

I have these tables in mysql:

```
table_brands - brand_id, brand_name
table_variants - variant_id, variant_name

table_products - product_id, product_name, brand_id
table_product_variants - product_id, variant_id (This table gives information for all available variants of all the products)

table_shop_product_variants - product_id, variant_id, shop_id (This table gives information for particular shop having only those variants of products)
```

to get count for all available brands, products and variants i am using this query.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) from table_brands), (SELECT COUNT(*) from table_products), (SELECT COUNT(*) from table_product_variants)
```

Now i want to get the count for brands, products and variants for particular shop say shop id 1. in other words i just want to know a particular shop have how many brands, products and variants out of all available brands, products and variants.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

select count(distinct prod.brandid), count (distinct prodid), count(distinct variantid) from shop, prod where shop.prodid = prod.id and shop.id=1